# Spring Data - CrudRepository - Query creation from method names

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a CrudRepository on customer table. When I tried to use the **findByName or findByNameAndDesc or findByEmailLike** are not working. But the the query being executed in the backend is correct. When I try the query in Oracle it fetches result.

**My Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CUST_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "CUSTOMERS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "CUST_SEQ")
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**My Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {
    
    //List<Customer> findByName(String name);
    
    List<Customer> findByName(String name);
    
    List<Customer> findByNameAndEmail(String name, String email);
 
    List<Customer> findByEmailLike(String email);
    
    List<Customer> findByIdIn(List<Integer> ids);
}
```

**My Hibernate Query on Log**

```
    Hibernate: select customer0_.id as id1_0_, customer0_.email as email2_0_, customer0_.name as name3_0_ from customer customer0_ where customer0_.name=?
```

What is the issue? Why spring always returns an empty list? Do I have to provide any configuration?

Comment: What is not working, are you not able to fetch data or you are getting any errors?

Comment: My Call List<Customer> customers=  repository.findByName("Rock"); returns an empty List, even though I have records in the table "Rock" as names. Why it is not giving me list containing record.  But when execute the query in the log in the sql developer , I get record

Comment: I m not sure if I understand your database structure. You have `Customer` database and `Rock` database?

Comment: are the queries invoked against the same database you use in sql developer? could there be some casing issues? as in at database level you stored a name in lowercase and you search for it in uppercase?